# Page reloads before it has a chance to render

Tags: networking, reload, cloudflare

I have a page that is loading once, then something is triggering a reload before the page code finishes rendering. The reload only happens once.

When I load this page up on my local, it loads only once. Same thing with the staging server.

When I load it on production, which is two servers behind an application load balancer, the page does this double loading thing.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to see what's causing this behavior only on production. Trying to stop the page from reloading never works so I can at least see the JS events and code.

The most mysterious thing is that this started happening at random without any code changes. This morning it suddenly stopped happening, then an hour later it started again.

I tried clearing our CloudFlare cache, but that didn't help.

What could be causing this?

Is there an app or Chrome tool I could use to capture the contents of every page in a series of redirects so I can at least get some visibility on this?

Comment: maybe this could help https://gist.github.com/InstanceOfMichael/f6a509b84fe82a718816

Comment: @MaMadLord that worked to stop the page, but when I step thru the code, I only see the JS that fires after the `beforeunload` event. I tried adding a listener for `load` so I can trace from the very first JS code executed but it's never hit. Any ideas?